# Is there a limit to the number of newsstand apps I can have installed?

Tags: ios, springboard, newsstand

Newsstand seems to be a fancy folder, contianing specific apps. Normal folders on iOS have a limited number of apps which they can contain.

Does newsstand inherit this limit, or does the scrolling shelf bypass this limitation? Is there a hard limit to the number of apps that one can have installed in Newsstand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shelf for a lot of subscriptions. Many more than the standard folder limits. As conceptually you could see it as a folder, but in fact its a newsstand. I tried to find some documentation on the limit for newsstand and couldn't find anything but I've seen some of my clients have a LOT of subscriptions on their shelves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. I just tried filling up my newsstand. As it appears, you only get to see a small bar when opening the application. In the small bar you can scroll through your subscriptions like on a real bookshelf. Very intuitive and smooth.

[image]